# IP4.ME and Tor report different IP addresses

Tags: anonymity, exit-relays, ip-address

Probably a complete noobie question.

I'm running TOR browser 7.5.  The browsers states

> Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor. Your IP
>   address appears to be: xx.xx.43.164

But when I go to IP4.ME it states

> You are connecting with an IPv4 Address of: yy.yy.78.21

Why the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser uses a different circuit for each domain (essentially "website") you visit.

If you read somewhere that "Tor (Browser) uses a new circuit every 10 minutes", that is a statement so oversimplified that it is incorrect.